# How to create this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to create this query (exercise included in Stanford Database MOOC):

> For all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice and gave it a higher rating the second time, return the reviewer's name and the title of the movie.

The system used is SQLite.

Table `movie`:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mID | int(11) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| title | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| year | int(11) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| director | text | YES |  | NULL |  |

Table `rating`:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rID | int(11) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| mID | int(11) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| stars | int(11) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| ratingDate | date | YES |  | NULL |  |

Table `reviewer`:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rID | int(11) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| name | text | YES |  | NULL |  |

Expected result:

| name | title |
| --- | --- |
| Sarah Martinez | Gone with the Wind |

[The data](https://class.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/moviedata.html).

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What lines were you thinking along for this query?

Comment: What “trouble” are you having, exactly?

Comment: I was thinking a lot and I know how to get the reviewers who have rated the same movie twice, but I have no idea how to apply the condition " and gave it a higher rating the second time"

Comment: @DourHighArch just see the comment above, the problem is with the logical construction of the query, if I got the steps, syntax would not be the problem I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   W.name,
   M.title
FROM
   reviewer AS R
   INNER JOIN movie AS M
      ON EXISTS ( -- there is at least one rating
         SELECT *
         FROM rating AS G
         WHERE
            -- by the reviewer and movie in question
            R.rID = G.rID
            AND M.mID = G.mID
            AND EXISTS ( -- for which another rating exists
               SELECT *
               FROM rating AS G2
               WHERE
                  -- for the same reviewer and movie
                  R.rID = G2.rID
                  AND M.mID = G2.mID
                  AND G.stars < G2.stars -- but rated higher
                  AND G.ratingDate < G2.ratingDate -- and later
            )
      )
;
```

I am not 100% sure if SQLite allows `ON` clauses to have `EXISTS` expressions. If not, you can just move the `EXISTS` expression to the `WHERE` clause and perform a cross join between `reviewer` and `movie`.

If SQLite doesn't support `EXISTS`, then put the `EXISTS` queries as a derived table in the `FROM` clause, with the two tables `INNER JOIN`ed to each other, and then `GROUP BY` the `mId` and the `rID`, then `INNER JOIN` to the main tables. That might look like this:

```
SELECT
   R.name,
   M.title
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         G.rID,
         G.mID
      FROM
         rating AS G
         INNER JOIN rating AS G2
            ON G.rID = G2.rID
            AND G.mID = G2.mID
            AND G.stars < G2.stars
            AND G.ratingDate < G2.ratingDate
      GROUP BY
         G.rID,
         G.mID
   ) C
   INNER JOIN reviewer AS R
      ON C.rID = R.rID
   INNER JOIN movie AS M
      ON C.mID = R.mID
;
```

I hope you can see how these two queries express the same semantics. In a very large database where people have rated the same movies many times, there could be a performance difference (the `EXISTS` version I first showed could perform better as it can stop as soon as it finds one result).

Note: You could just join the whole mess into a single query and `GROUP BY` the `name`, `title`, `rID`, `mID`, but while "simpler", that would be more wrong, as there is no need to duplicate the name and title for many rows, only to throw away that information by grouping. The grouping should happen as early as possible.

Comment: that works, thanks, but it is so complicated for me, do you think it is the the shortest possible solution or could be there something more simple? but thanks anyway

Comment: In many ways, this IS the simplest solution. Other solutions require gymnastics to get rid of the row duplication that results from them. I will endeavor to show a "simpler" version for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this specific exercise with this query:

```
SELECT R.name, M.title
FROM
    Rating AS RatingLatest
JOIN Rating AS R2 
    ON RatingLatest.rID = R2.rID AND R1.mID = R2.mID
JOIN Reviewer AS R USING (rID)
JOIN Movie AS M USING (mID)
-- Check if there is a newer rating with more stars than the previous one 
WHERE RatingLatest.ratingDate > R2.ratingDate 
AND RatingLatest.stars > R2.stars
```

It returns reviewers where it has rated the same movie more than once and when, on the last time (not specifically the second), the rating was greater.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```sql
select yes1.name,yes1.title from (select yes. name, yes. title,d.stars,d.rating date,(rank() over(partition by yes.name order by d.stars desc)) as rankk1,(rank() over(partition by yes.name order by d.ratingDate asc )) as rankk2
from (select c.mID,a.rID,a.name,c.title from Reviewer as a join Rating as b on a.rID=b.rID
join Movie as c on b.mID=c.mID group by a.name,c.title,c.mID,a.riD having count(*)=2) as yes join Rating as d on yes.mID = d.mID and yes.riD = d.rID) as yes1 where yes1.rankk1 = 1 and yes1.rankk2=2;
```

I followed the simple analytical approach and got the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**